# Как в списке поменять местами элементы?

Tags: python

Хочу сделать простенькую программа,которая будет демонстрировать сортировку выбором.Существует ли функция для списка,которая сможет поменять местами(индексами) 2 элемента.Пример кода:

```
`m_list=[1,2,4,6,3,5]
for current(1,len(m_list)-1):
    smallest=current
    for i(current+1,len(m_list)):
        if m_list[i]<m_list[smallest]:
            smallest=i
    #далее нужно чтобы элементы с индексами current и smallest менялись местами`
```

Answer (score 3):

```
m_list[current], m_list[smallest] = m_list[smallest], m_list[current]
```